# How to find the keys of duplicate entries in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm reporting on appointment activity and have included a function to export the raw data behind the KPIs. This raw data is stored as a CSV and I need to check for potentially duplicate consultations that have been entered.

Each row of data is assigned a unique visit ID based on the patients ID and the appointment ID. The raw data contains 30 columns of data, the duplicate check only needs to be performed on 7 of these. I have imported the CSV and created an array as below for first record and then append rest on.

```
$mds = array(
    $unique_visit_id => array(
        $appt_date, 
        $dob, 
        $site, 
        $CCG, 
        $GP, 
        $appt_type, 
        $treatment_scheme
    )
);
```

What I need is to scan the `$mds` array and return an array containing just the `$unique_visit_id` for any duplicate arrays.

e.g. keys 1111, 2222 and 5555 all references arrays that contain the same value for all seven values, then I would need 2222 and 5555 returned.

I've tried search but not coming up with anything that is working.

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far, share  some of your code ... where you stuck ?

Comment: why is 1111 more important than 2222 and 5555 ? what do you intend to do with the list (ie could  you need more than the ID of the dupes) ?  show your code.

Comment: Please show us some stuff that you tried. It would help us understand your question better.

Comment: Checking for “combined” uniqueness across those seven fields will become a little easier, if you concatenate all those values together, and store them in an extra field. If you then order your array by the content of that extra field, you can loop over the data afterwards, and check if the value of the current record is the same as for the previous one - if so, you know that the current record is a duplicate. […]

Comment: […] If it is important which of those records you get as result (has to be 2222 and 5555, and not maybe 1111 and 2222, or 1111 and 5555 instead) - then you need to sort by two criteria, the concatenated “7-in-1” value first, and whatever decides the order of those records second.

Comment: thank you @misorude got hung up trying to solve it as 2D array. I've simplified the import into it just being a one dimensional array with a concatenated string representation of the data and sorted the results to make it a simple foreach step through saving any keys that match previous entry.

Comment: apologies for not posting more code, first question and didn't realise will make sure to next time, thanks again (and no it isn't important which ID)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've gone with, still validating (data set is very big) but seems to be functioning as expected so far

```
$handle = fopen("../reports/mds_full_export.csv", "r");

$visits = array();

while($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,',','"') !== FALSE){
    $key = $data['unique_visit_id'];
    $value = $data['$appt_date'].$data['$dob'].$data['$site'].$data['$CCG'].$data['$GP'].$data['$appt_type'].$data['$treatment_scheme'];
  $visits[$key] = $value;
}

$visits = asort($visits);
$previous = "";
$dupes = array();

foreach($visits as $id => $visit){ 
    if(strcmp($previous, $visit) == 0){
        $dupes[] = $id;
    }
    $previous = $visit;
}

return $dupes;
```